# Swagger connected to Azure ..now what?

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I connected my swagger PetStore api to Azure using swagger Azure API Management integration.

Now that it made it in azure; Where do I implement the actual logic of querying my azure database etc?
[image: api in azure]

Using swagger if I generate a Node server stub I get the following generated. But these are not available if I use API management integration.

[image]

In the Backend section I only see Logic Apps and endpoint options. I tried the Logic App stuff but it seems I need 50 logic apps if I have api that large...Am I missing something?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `SwaggerHub`.

The `Swagger UI` you are currently using belongs to the community version and should not support direct integration. Assuming there are 100 api interfaces, you need to add 100 times in azure apim.

[image]

Comment: i was able to connect to azure fine using SwaggerHub trial. What I am asking is once I get the api in Azure APIM i dont see a way to query azure db and return value for example. I have to use LogicApps to be able to do that. Which means each api end is going to need a logic app to do its job...

Comment: After your node api project is deployed, can the interfaces in swagger api be used normally?

Comment: you can use swagger interface to design the API anytime and azure will update if i push new design from swagger. But the backend of the API ; connection to DB or other apis has to be done somewhere else.